# MySQL query not offsetting correctly

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me understand why the following query is not offsetting correctly?

It's meant to select all records in the games table, and add a column with a value of 0 or 1 based on whether a record in another table (wishlist) exists with the same gameId @memberId (in plain English, get me all records from games, and mark any game that exists in the wishlists table, under whatever memberId I give you)

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN wishlists.memberid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS InMembersList

FROM games
    INNER JOIN platforms ON games.platformid = platforms.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wishlists ON games.id = wishlists.gameid and wishlists.memberid = @memberId

WHERE platforms.platformUrlId = @platformUrlId

ORDER BY releaseDate DESC

LIMIT 1,8
```

When I change the offset from 1 to 2, or 3, or whatever, many of the same records appear, which does not make any sense. Where am I going wrong?

Schema:

```
platforms(id, platform)
members(id, name)
games(id, platformId, releaseDate)
wishlists(id, memberId, gameId)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIMIT 1,8` means start from row number 1 (they start from 0) and fetch 8 rows. So `LIMIT 2,8` will give you 8 rows starting from row 2 - seven of which will be the same as with `LIMIT 1,8`

Comment: Complete muppetry on my part! I forgot I was meant to multiply offset * limit to get the correct pagination!